# 'showPDF' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, html, function

some background information: i have a button in my html file that should activate the showPDF function but it tells me that its value is never read

[image: picture of the error message]

javascript:

```
HM.PDFViewer = 
{
    init: function()
    {
        //---
    },
    showPDF: function()
    {
        function showPDF(x) {
            x.style.display = "none";
            var embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
            embed.setAttribute("src", "/pdf/Doku.pdf");
            embed.classList.add("size");
            document.body.appendChild(embed);
          }
    },
};
```

the button in my html looks like this:

```
<button type="button" id="show" onclick="showPDF(this)" >PDF anzeigen</button>
```

help would be greatly appreciated as i can't seem to find any answers in different questions

Comment: Why do you have nested `showPDF` function?

Comment: to be honest i have no clue what i'm doing i just started with js a week ago and still learning

Comment: I just provide an answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the duplication of the `showPDF` function. you don't need the inner one.

```
showPDF: function()
{
        x.style.display = "none";
        var embed = document.createElement("EMBED");
        embed.setAttribute("src", "/pdf/Doku.pdf");
        embed.classList.add("size");
        document.body.appendChild(embed);
},
```

Comment: thank you, but now when i press the button i get the error message ***Uncaught ReferenceError: showPDF is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick***

Comment: You are welcome because as you have shown in the question, the `showPDF` function is inside another object `HM.PDFViewer`, So I think you may need to update your `click` handler with `onclick="HM.PDFViewer.showPDF(this)"`

Comment: thank you so much now it's working as intended